# 'Have you?' vs. 'Do you?' after 'I've had a lot of fun!'

Tags: tag-questions

> Jair: I've had a lot of fun! *Have you*? (1)
>
> Jair: I've had a lot of fun! *Do you*? (2)

Which is correct, if any, '*Do you*?' or '*Have you*?'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Have you* can work:

> I've had a lot of fun! Have you [had a lot of fun]?

*Do you* is in the wrong tense. You can fix that in one of two ways:

> I've **had** a lot of fun! **Did** you [have a lot of fun]?
>   I **have** a lot of fun! **Do** you [have a lot of fun]?

You'd use the first when, say, you're looking back on the end of a long, fun-filled day. You'd use the second when you're talking about a general trend of several fun experiences in the past, where you expect that fun to continue for some time into the foreseeable future. There's one more way you could say it:

> I had a lot of fun; did you?

This is much like the first one, but you'd use this one when more time has elapsed between when the speaking is talking, and when the fun happened.

Comment: I would have upvoted, but I don't have enough rep. +1, even if virtually and thank you.

Comment: Thanks for catching (and fixing) my error. That's thanks enough :^)

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo You can't upvote yet, but you can click the check mark beneath this answer to accept it if it helped you :)

Comment: @WendiKidd - That's true, but I always encourage users to wait half a day or so before accepting. That makes it more likely someone else might write an answer, and there's a chance that answer would be better than the first.

Comment: A complete and to the point answer. I don't believe there are more points left to the discussion to be pointed to by giving a separate answer.

Comment: @Mistu4u - Perhaps, but I still think it's good decorum to wait half a day or so. I look at it from the point of view of a user who logs in at say, noontime, only to find six or eight new questions – all of them resolved. There's not much harm in leaving questions open for a few extra hours, if not a full day. It's not like an O.P. gains extra rep by selecting an answer quickly. Moreover, I've seen a first answer accepted when it was outright **wrong**, with bad advice. It's happened more than a few times. An answer can **seem** to accurately answer a question when it really doesn't.

Comment: @J.R., Yeah, seems reasonable. :-)